# Determine which ropes are under tension in pulley systems

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

[image]

These questions is gotten from beer and Johnston vector mechanics, the solution manual reveals:

i) the two portions ropes are under tension in (a) - *this I understand*

ii) only two out of the three portions are under tension in (b)- *I am lost at this point*

iii) the three portions are experiencing tension in (c) , three out of four portions in (d) and the four portions in (e)

How does one know which portions are experiencing tension

**By portion I mean a parts of the rope to any sides of a pulley**

Answer (score 2):

In all of the cases the tension is the same in *all* parts of the rope. If the weight of the box is in each case $Mg$, then you can equate the weight to the tension in the ropes *supporting the box* to see that

a) T=Mg/2

b) T=Mg/2

c) T=Mg/3

d) T=Mg/3

e) T=Mg/4